# MpMath package not importing correctly

Tags: python, mpmath

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'rational' from 'mpmath'
```

When I run my code

```
from mpmath import *
from sympy import Function, Symbol, Derivative, dsolve, log, exp, sin, cos, pi

from sympy.plotting import plot
```

I get an error `ImportError: cannot import name 'rational' from 'mpmath'` and I have no clue why?
any help would be much appreciated
Thanks